# Syncronizing mySQL database using myPHPAdmin

Tags: mysql, synchronization

I'm trying to synchronize two mySQL databases - more specifically, copy the contents of one to another.

I have been using the myPHPAdmin Synchronize function but the target database does seems to have rows missing from it.

The data is in english, with some numeric fields too.  As a result there special characters such as commas, apostophries, ampersands etc.

Could that be the reason and if so, how do I get round it?

Any help would be warmly welcomed.

Chris.

Comment: Do you mean phpMyAdmin? Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you just need a one-time copy, or do they have to continually stay in sync? And do you have SSH access?

In case of a one-time copy, it is pretty straightforward to use mysqldump to dump one db and import it into a new db to make a duplicate.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-copy-mysql-database-remote-server.html

Comment: I need to make copies on demand to promote data from a test to a live db. The command line examples look good but could give you point me in the right direction of how to run these.  I access the server through cPanel and myPHPAdmin and then through PHP scripts. One idea I had was to run it through a cron job but that seems to be using a slightly unsuitable sledgehammer to crack a nut as I want it to run on demand, not regularly.

Comment: Thanks @opsguy - I wrote a php script with the commands in the link you gave.  Now works with whole database but am just stuggling to get it to work for a specific table where I am simply adding the table name to the end of each part of the command i.e. mysqldump -u testUser -p'xxxxxx' testDB tableFoo | mysql -u liveUser -p'yyyyyy' liveDB tableFoo

Comment: Check this out: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx

Specifically the system() part. Apparently phpmyadmin also has an export ability, although not sure how the import works but its worth looking at that as well I'd say.

Comment: Hrm interesting. Does it give you an error when you run that or what?

Comment: Does the liveUser have full privileges on liveDB? It needs to be able to drop/lock tables.